# Required fields check in asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I implement a clientsidevalidation required textfields which contain the following texts:

[Name required]
[Address required]

Preferrably I would like to use the asp:CustomValidator if possible? Only if both fields have data the postback will be triggered?

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function otherMessageValidator_ClientValidation(source, args) {
            args.IsValid = false;

            var nm = $j("#name");

            if (nm.val() != "" && nm.val() != "[Name required]") {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }

            return args.IsValid;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valgroup">[Name required]</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="address" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valgroup">[Address required]</asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="but1" Text="go" OnClick="but1_Click" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="MyCustomValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valgroup"
        ClientValidationFunction="otherMessageValidator_ClientValidation" ErrorMessage="At least one textbox needs to be filled in." />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And you don't want to use two RequiredFieldValidators because...? You only want one validation message? For CustomValidator, you would use ClientValidationFunction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is by using regular expression from javascript and validation it client side only. So in the mentioned code it will only go to server if all the required validations are fulfilled else it will show the Error message on the screen in the Summary div tag.

Following is the required code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">               
 function validateFields() {

                var message = "";
                var error = false;

               var name = document.getElementById("<%=txtname.ClientID %>");
                var address = document.getElementById("<%=txtaddress.ClientID %>");

                //work as required field validation
                if ((/\S+/.test(name.value)) == false) {

                    message += "Enter Name" + "<br>";
                    error = true;
                }
                //work as required field validation
                if ((/\S+/.test(address.value)) == false) {

                    message += "Enter Address" + "<br>";
                    error = true;
                }


                if (error) {
                        document.getElementById("validationSummary").innerHTML = message;
                        document.getElementById("validationSummary").style.display = "block";
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("validationSummary").innerHTML = "";
                        document.getElementById("validationSummary").style.display = "none";
                        return true;
                    }


                }
 </script>
```

and we need to take one div for displaying validationsummary and the button

```
<div id="validationSummary" style="display: none; float: left">
                                </div>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNew" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validateFields()" OnClick="lnkAddNewPatient_Click" >Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

Hope it will solve your issue